# Accessing variables of a C++ class with ECS:Python

Tags: python, c++

I have a class (like below) in C++. I can use ECS:Python to run python scripts that can run `doSomething()` on an exposed instance of the `Foo` class. However, Any time I try to do anything with `i` (set its value to another variable or change the value) in this function I get the error "Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF". I do not get the same error running `doSomething` on the same instance of `Foo` from C++. Is there a way I can get around this?

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo();

    int i;

    void doSomething(int R);

};
```